# ThreadGroup execution on Dedicated VM using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using below test plan for testing.
MyTestThreadGroup (Concurrent users:5)
IfController(${__groovy( "${__machineIP()}"!="10.0.0.4")}
Request1
This threadgroup will spin 5 concurrentuser for given duration of test. If IP matches it will execute Request1. If IP does not match it wont execute request1, but does it spin 5 concurrent users even if condition/IP does not match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.

If you don't want to kick off 5 users if the IP address is not the one you're looking for you can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

```
${__groovy(if (org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP()=='10.0.0.4') return '0' else return '5',)}
```

[image]

Also don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts, go for code-based equivalents instead, i.e. instead of `${__machineIP()}` use [JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html#getLocalHostIP--) function

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, Appreciate your help.  If we want to execute with 5 concurrent users only when IP Address is not in (10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2). How can we write the condition ?